# Copy files from wp8 to windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-7-x64

Hi I need to connect wp8 to windows 7 machine through USB and copy the screenshots from my running wp8 app.

Is it possible?

I done this in windows 8 using microsoft smart phone connectviy but for windows 7 it is not working.

Comment: Why not send them by email?

Comment: Actually i am developing a streaming of my app on pc.

Comment: If you have something working in one environment can you show where it's not working on the other? What errors do you get?

Comment: Actually I am using smartphone.connectivity dll for communication but dll is not working.